# CSS Inner Border?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created the button on the left purely with CSS. It is a div within a div. However, the three buttons on the right are `background` properties on `img` tags. I did this so I could simulate a rollover effect following instructions from [here](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/pure-css-image-hover/).

[image]

Now, is there a way to add the inner border, as in the first button, to the other three using CSS?

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gB8j/).

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to add it to the image itself?

Comment: First, how would you do that? Second, let's say it isn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), padding is between the *content* and *border*. You should be able to style the images like:

```
 .img-btn {
     background: #FFF; // inner border color
     padding: 2px; // inner border width
     border: 2px solid #[yourgreen]; // outer border
 }
```

You shouldn't need any extra `div`s to accomplish this, even for your pure CSS button. Following style is for the case when the image is a background-image:

```
.img-btn {
    background: #FFF url('your.img') no-repeat;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 2px solid #[yourgreen];
    width: [image width];
    height: [image height];
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rgrFs/) of double-border as described above.

Comment: Doesn't `background` with the color and the image I want to set conflict here?

Comment: @awfullyjohn It shouldn't, you can have both a background-color and background-image. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need two `<divs>` and an `<a>` to do the button. You can do it with a single `<a>`. For both the images and the button you can use `box-shadow` to do the outer border. Center the `background-images` in the `<img>` elements.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/bNmzB/

Output:

[image]

HTML:

```html
<a id="add" href="#">Add To Cart</a>
<img id="facebook" class="icon" />
<img id="twitter" class="icon" />
<img id="email" class="icon" />
```

CSS:

```css
#add {
    background-color: #9bc9c7;
    border: 1px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #9bc9c7;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal 13px/25px Helvetica, Arial, Sans Serif;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 120px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#add:hover {
    background-color: #eabeb2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #eabeb2;
}

.icon {
    background-color: rgb( 155, 201, 199 );
    border: 1px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgb( 155, 201, 199 );
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    width: 25px;       
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will do start doing it this way +1

Comment: Clever! It's worth noting, though, that `box-shadow` is [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/), so browser compatibility may be an issue. In particular, it's [not supported in IE 8 and below](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-shadow).

Comment: @awfullyjohn Just looked at your demo link. You can do the button with *just* the anchor. I updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same approach as you did for the button - just treat the icons as background images to  the inner div. So you should have a div with some padding, an inner div(in your case img) with a white border, and a background image (the icons.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't modify the icon images directly, just wrap them in a div in the same way as "Add to Cart". You'll also need to use either

```
background-position: center center;
```

to ensure that the icon stays centered within the smaller img, and/or

```
background-size: 24px 24px;
```

to scale the background down a bit so the white border doesn't run into the symbols.