# How to draw a border within an image?

Tags: css

I'm trying to draw a border within an image but separated from the edge without any success so far. Please, see an example

[image]

Comment: Please, provide some code. It could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code. **[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159977/inner-border-over-images-with-css)**

```
img {
  outline: 1px solid white;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for everybody. I've finally test the solution provided by Microsmsn and it works perfectly. Easiest and best solution

Answer (score 1):

Place one div on top of another using absolute positioning on the second div, and relative on the first. Then set your image as the background on the bottom div. The top div then need to have a border and a transparent background: https://jsfiddle.net/5r1st8cL/

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>

  .one {
    background-image: url('');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
 }
 .two {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid black;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    background: transparent;
  }
```