# Offset a border over an image

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to create exactly like what is shown in the picture below. I have tried other methods using outline and offset method too but I could't figure out how to go on about doing this.

[image: image with an offset border]

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p87ssyrL/):

```css
img {
  border: 4px solid green;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/cxwWPa/services_gas_oil.jpg" alt="services_gas_oil" border="0">
```

How do I do to get this offset border over the image?

Comment: OP wants the effect similar to the displayed picture. @DarrenSweeney

Comment: Do you know the size of the image?

Comment: It's a responsive website and won't want to put restriction on size. Thank you though. I got the answer from Ori :)

Comment: Possible duplicate (accepted answer's 2nd option) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159977/inner-border-over-images-with-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner border over images with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159977/inner-border-over-images-with-css)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wrap the image with an inline block, and set an absolutely positioned pseudo-element as the border:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px 0 0 80px;
}

.imageContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.imageContainer::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  left: -15%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #77B244;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/31/12/25/cat-169095_960_720.jpg" alt="services_gas_oil" border="0">
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

A simpler way would be to use a combination of border, outline and a negative [outline-offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset). Here is an example :

```css
img{
  outline:4px solid #77B244;
  outline-offset:-100px;
  border:50px solid transparent;
  border-width:150px 50px 50px 150px;
  margin:-75px 0 0 -75px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/cxwWPa/services_gas_oil.jpg" alt="services_gas_oil" border="0">
```

This prevents the use of a parent element and a pseudo element.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to wrap image inside a `div` element having a border and move image inside container towards left and bottom.

As from [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Types_of_positioning):

> A **relatively positioned element** is an element whose computed `position` value is `relative`. The `top` and `bottom` properties specify the vertical offset from its normal position; the `left` and `right` properties specify the horizontal offset.

We will need to wrap `img` inside an element like `div` i.e:

```
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cxwWPa/services_gas_oil.jpg" >
</div>
```

We will apply `border` to the container and move image from its normal position with following CSS:

```
.image-holder img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```css
.image-holder {
  border: 7px solid #76af46;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.image-holder img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cxwWPa/services_gas_oil.jpg" alt="services_gas_oil" border="0">
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, we can use CSS3 `translate()` as well.

```
.image-holder img {
  transform: translate(40px, 40px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```css
.image-holder {
  border: 7px solid #76af46;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.image-holder img {
  transform: translate(40px, 40px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cxwWPa/services_gas_oil.jpg" alt="services_gas_oil" border="0">
</div>
```