# How to make thick border OVER image without changing the image size

Tags: html, css

The problem is i need photoshop-like selection functionality. But when I add border to div that encloses the image, the image gets smaller by the thickness of the border x2.

How can i resolve that?

I tried, making

```css
.picture-frame--image {
    border: 5px solid red;
  margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img class="picture-frame--image" src="https://placehold.it/500x500">
</div>

<div>
<img src="https://placehold.it/500x500">
</div>
```

but the image is overlapping border, and i need otherwise. For some reason z-index won't work, i dont know why.

Comment: did you try outline instead?

Comment: Hi please post your code here so your question is reproducible and solveable. Have you tried outline instead of border? Outline doesn't take up space on the container so should work and not reduce the image dimentions.You will probably need overflow hidden on the div so the outline doesn't go past the edge of the image.

Comment: Some good ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159977/inner-border-over-images-with-css outline-offset is the negative opposite to the width of the outline. So outline 5px use outline-offset of -5.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, outline with outline-offset -2px helps

Answer (score 1):

Accualy the best answer was made by cimmanon in nathaniel link.

I made:

```
img {
  outline: 2px dashed violet;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Thank you all for the answers. Really appreacie it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

to your css file. I'm not entirely sure though because you didn't post any code.
Check this site for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are pseudo elements like `::after` and `::before`. With these you can add content around your element. But beware that these can only be applied to certain html tags. [::after MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

See this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-wteuji?file=styles.css)

Comment: I edited the StackBlitz to work with your code